# Duplicate edit bones

Tags: python, armature

I want to loop through my skeleton and duplicate each bone but also making the new duplicated bone parent to the original bone. Kinda like this:

```
for bone in bpy.context.active_object.data.edit_bones[:]:
    new_bone = bone.duplicate_move()
    bone.parent = new_bone
```

But this results in this error: `AttributeError: 'EditBone' object has no attribute 'duplicate_move'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `bone.duplicate_move`  There is a `bpy.ops.armature.duplicate(...)` but being an operator it wont return the newly created bone(s) only a status set.  `{'FINISHED'}` if run succesfully for instance.

Need something like (run in edit mode ofcourse)

```
import bpy
arm = bpy.context.object.data
for b in arm.edit_bones[:]:
    cb = arm.edit_bones.new(b.name)

    cb.head = b.head
    cb.tail = b.tail
    cb.matrix = b.matrix
    cb.parent = b
```

Comment: Can I ask why assign the bones head and tail if we are assigning the whole matrix anyway? Just writing `cb.matrix = b.matrix` mostly doesn't work for some reason. This works `cb.matrix = b.matrix.copy()` but is slow, weirdly. Writing it the way you did works much faster, do you know why?